# Lights don’t work after installing single pole switch

Tags: wiring, bedroom

I have one black wire and one red wire in a bedroom switch.I connected the black to line (bottom screw) and red to load (top screw). Bedroom ceiling light and bedroom closet light don’t turn on. All outlets in room  work. Everything else on the circuit works.  There is no ground wire. I was replacing a dimmer with single pole toggle switch.

Comment: Please post clear photos. There may be something that you're not noticing.

Comment: Were both of those lights controlled by the same dimmer? Have you checked the bubs?

Comment: Are you sure it's a single pole switch?

Comment: Turn the lever of your dimmer all the way up. I found this out from my dimmer switch (the switch controls the circuit, but the dimmer control the intensity of light, 0 - maximum :).

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?